# Mysql trigger after delete from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, triggers, multiple-tables

Hello I create trigger after delete and there is still error: Unknown column 'OLD.merchant_id' in 'where clause'

```
DELETE FROM on_size WHERE merchant_id=OLD.merchant_id;
DELETE FROM on_category WHERE merchant_id=OLD.merchant_id;
DELETE FROM on_item WHERE merchant_id=OLD.merchant_id;
DELETE FROM on_merchant_user WHERE merchant_id=OLD.merchant_id;
DELETE FROM on_offers WHERE merchant_id=OLD.merchant_id;
DELETE FROM on_rating WHERE merchant_id=OLD.merchant_id;
DELETE FROM on_review WHERE merchant_id=OLD.merchant_id;
DELETE FROM on_voucher WHERE merchant_id=OLD.merchant_id;
DELETE FROM on_voucher_new WHERE merchant_id=OLD.merchant_id;
DELETE ord,ord_da,ord_det,ord_his,ord_sms
FROM on_order ord
JOIN on_order_delivery_address ord_da ON ord.order_id=ord_da.order_id
JOIN on_order_details ord_det ON ord.order_id=ord_det.order_id
JOIN on_order_history ord_his ON ord.order_id=ord_his.order_id
JOIN on_order_sms ord_sms ON ord.order_id=ord_sms.order_id
WHERE ord.merchant_id=OLD.merchant_id;
```

Can I delete multiple tables in trigger?
Only on_order can be identified with merchant_id other tables haven't this.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no aliace for any table in the name of OLD (OR) There is no  table in the name of OLD

Comment: I try use special operators NEW, OLD which may me return OLD.merchant_id => ID of merchant which is deleted. Is it mistake? Can I use OLD after delete?

Comment: Can  you please Post your Full Trigger code ..

Comment: Sure I update my code. I use Navicat, then is there checkbox - Fires: after delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing BEGIN and END.
After the statement is all ok.

Comment: this should really be a comment